# Scala how to sum a list of futures

Tags: scala

I have written this code and it works

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Random}

object TestFuture2 {
  def bigCalc() : Future[Int] = Future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    40
  }
}

object Main2 extends App {
  val x = TestFuture2.bigCalc
  val y = TestFuture2.bigCalc
  val z = TestFuture2.bigCalc

  val v = for {
    r1 <- x
    r2 <- y
    r3 <- z
  } yield (r1 + r2 + r3)

  v onSuccess {
    case x1 => println(x1)
  }
  System.in.read()
}
```

So when I run this, I get 120. Good.

but I don't like that I am summing the values in a for loop

```
for {
  r1 <- x
  r2 <- y
  r3 <- z
} yield (r1 + r2 + r3)
```

What if I called my functions like

```
val x = List(TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc)
```

now how will I sum?

I tried

```
x.reduce(_ + _)
```

but that doesn't work.

```
scala> x.reduce(_ + _)
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
 required: String
              x.reduce(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Future.sequence` transforms a `Traversable[Future[T]]` into a `Future[Traversable[T]]` (this future will be failed, if any of the futures in the original list failed). After that you can simply call `sum` on the content of this Future:

```
Future.sequence(x).map(_.sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Use: `Future.reduce(futures)(_ + _)`

The main issue with your sample of code is the confusion between `Traversable#reduce` and `Future#reduce`. You want to use the second but you use the first.

The `Traversable#reduce` needs a reduction function that has this signature: `Tuple2[Future[Int], Future[Int]] => Future[Int]`.

The `Future#reduce` on the other hand will automatically unpack the values stored in the futures for you. It needs a reduction function with this signature: `Tuple2[Int, Int] => Int`. A lot more practical.

An example using the `Traversable#reduce` function:

```
val futures = List(TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc)
val reduced = futures.reduce((first: Future[Int], second: Future[Int]) => first.flatMap(firstResult => second.map(secondResult => secondResult + firstResult)))
```

An example using the `Future#reduce` function:

```
val futures = List(TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc, TestFuture2.bigCalc)
val reduced = Future.reduce(futures)((first: Int, second: Int) => first + second)
```

You can directly use `Future#sequence` instead, as this is what `Future#reduce` uses it under the hood. But why would you use the latter then? It returns a future failure if your list is empty. So usage of one or the other depends on your requirements. If the list should never be empty, use `Future#reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use reduce you can do it like this.

```scala
  list.reduce((future1, future2) =>
      future1.zip(future2).map(pair => pair._1 + pair._2))
    .onComplete({ case Success(value) => println(value)})
```